# Can't remove just one Set-Cookie header in HAProxy 2.2

Tags: haproxy

A response from our web server might set a few cookies:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=123;Secure
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=234;Secure
```

In HAProxy, we want to remove one of these. With 1.7, we could do:

```
rspidel ^Set-Cookie:\ JSESSIONIDSSO=
```

But we are upgrading to HAProxy 2.2, where `rspidel` has been removed. The replacement (`http-response del-header`) does not handle regex. How can I remove just the one Set-Cookie header?

Answer (score 1):

*Response edited because I misunderstood the question*

I believe you are looking for http-response replace-header

```
http-response replace-header <name> <regex-match> <replace-fmt>
                             [ { if | unless } <condition> ]

  This works like "http-request replace-header" except that it works on the
  server's response instead of the client's request.

  Example:
    http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (C=[^;]*);(.*) \1;ip=%bi;\2

    # applied to:
    Set-Cookie: C=1; expires=Tue, 14-Jun-2016 01:40:45 GMT

    # outputs:
    Set-Cookie: C=1;ip=192.168.1.20; expires=Tue, 14-Jun-2016 01:40:45 GMT

    # assuming the backend IP is 192.168.1.20.
```

Documentation [here](https://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy-2.2.git;a=blob;f=doc/configuration.txt;h=77f033b317df0f8e82610f572f11a1fe6f4f8e5a;hb=HEAD#l6356)

You can possibly do something like this:

```
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (JSESSIONIDSSO=.*) \2
```

Although, that would leave you with an empty Set-Cookie header.

Another option, would be to replace the value JSESSIONIDSSO with something else. i.e.

```
http-response replace-header Set-Cookie (JSESSIONIDSSO=[^;]*);(.*) None=None;\2
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the docs, it says ```<meth>
is the matching method, applied on the header name``` I'm actually trying to match on the cookie name (JSESSIONIDSSO) which is part of the value.